# Rails 3.2.12 Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mass-assignment

Here is my RubyOnRails application. I have an ActiveRecord:

```
class Deposit < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :fk, :abs_kod, :neres
    ...
end
```

also I have a controller with code:

```
list.each do |d_item|
      deposit = Deposit.find_or_create_by_fk(d_item[:fk])
      deposit.update_attributes d_item
end
```

But I can't save any value into "neres" field. I got an error

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: neres
```

and in my database I see

```
|  fk  | abs_kod |  neres |
|  1   | 1       |        |
```

I tried to do like this

```
deposit = Deposit.find_or_create_by_fk(d_item[:fk])
deposit.neres = d_item[:neres]
deposit.update_attributes d_item
deposit.neres = d_item[:neres] //twice, just in case
```

I doesn't help. Also I tried to remove attr_accessible from active record at all. It also doesn't help.  What's the problem?

P.S.: Attribure "neres" was added later than "abs_kod" and "fk".

Answer (score 0):

To use strong params in Rails apps less than version 4, you need to add the gem to your gem file

```
gem 'strong_parameters'
```

and in the application.rb file in config set whitelist_attributes to false

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

In the controller, be sure to add a model_params method and list the attributes that need to be whitelisted.